# Android detect position of ViewGroup Child

Tags: android, android-layout

So I really  have two related questions on `ViewGroups`:

1. Is a `LinearLayout` and instance of `ViewGroup`? Meaning, can I call `getChildAt(index)` when using a `LinearLayout`?
2. Can I detect when a `ViewGroup` child is at the "top" of the screen (right below the action bar) after scrolling? For example, when the 3rd child is scrolled to the top

I'm working on an app that utilizes Parallax Scrolling and I'm using an open source library that has a custom `View` with a `LinearLayout` as a child and 4 `TextViews` as the `LinearLayouts` children. In their custom `View` class they are calling `getChildAt` but I can't seem to find documentation on that related to `LinearLayouts` so I wanted to check. And essentially I want to check if one of these `TextViews` are at the top of the screen. Any clairfication would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**question 1** { *Is a LinearLayout and instance of ViewGroup? Meaning, can I call getChildAt(index) when using a LinearLayout?* }

**answer** = yes... *A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views containers* .. so your linear layout is a view because it extends view, and if it contains other sub views called children then it's a viewgroup.. viewgroup extends view.. Meaning YES you can call `getChildAt(index)` when using linear layout..

**question 2** { *Can I detect when a ViewGroup child is at the "top" of the screen (right below the action bar)?* }.

**answer**  YES , you can check the **Z order** of the children in a viewgroup(a view containing other sub views) to know its position, so probably your first child is the child below the actionbar, that's if your viewgroup (that is the linear layout) is the view content of your activity - which is always the case right? - yea..

if you want a documentation on `getChildAt` and viewgroups in general then [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) ..

hope it helps.. let me know anything that's arising..

Comment: So for my second question, what I meant was can I detect when a child is at the top of the screen after scrolling? So when child 3 is at the "top" of the screen for example

Comment: well with that, i am thinking you need to hack it, by using the logic of, onscroll listener and getting the visible item count and subtracting it from your child count/totalItemCount.. or checking simply the first visible item which is not 0..so you get the index and pull it from your viewgroup. do i make sense @RyanSayles

Comment: but i tot you was using a linear layout right?@RyanSayles

Comment: I'm using a linear layout inside of my custom layout.

Comment: And I think I understand what you are saying